# How to Verify If the Database Connection is Successfully Established?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

## The Controller:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Private Sub SqlClientPermission(value As Boolean)
        allowBlankPassword = True
    End Sub


    Function CreateCommand() As SqlCommand

        Dim sqlconnectionCommand As New SqlConnection("Data Source=MSSQLSERVER;server=(localdb)\v11.0;User Id=xxxx_user;Password=;Database=ColorTable_database.sdf;Integrated Security=false;")

        sqlconnectionCommand.OpenAsync()
        sqlconnectionCommand.RetrieveStatistics()

        Dim sqlqueryString As String = "SELECT ColorTable.* FROM ColorTable"
        Dim sqlqueryCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlqueryString, sqlconnectionCommand)

        'Printing Out the SQL Result

        Return ViewData("sqlqueryCommand")

    End Function
```

## The Question:

How can I verify the *connection* to the database, to see if it is successfully established?

I tried it with `RetriveStatistics()`, yet I am having a `blank` page (or result) in the web browser.

**EDIT:** In this example there is no exception to be handled, as said I am having a blank page, and I am looking to be confirmed that the connection to the database is working, before further proceeding.

**The Tools Used:** *Visual Studio 2012, VB .NET 4.5 MVC 4, Microsoft SQL Server Express*

Answer (score 1):

You would typically not explicity verify the conneciton, but instead just use it, and handle the exception.

Comment: In this example there is no exception to be handled, as said I am having a blank page, and I am looking to be confirmed that the connection to the database is working, before further proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch was correct: The connection is probably not established.

You are calling `OpenAsync` which is, well, async. The process is not complete when it returns! It looks like what you want is to call `Open`. When that call is done without exception the connection is working. No need to verify.